# Problem with starting FiftyOne app with Python

Tags: python, dataset, localhost, fiftyone

I have a problem when i try to start FiftyOne. I installed it without problem, but, when i want to launch app to see the dataset i downloaded, the terminal says "App launched. Point your web browser to http://localhost:5151". But, when i go the the url, there is the error connection refused.

I'm on Windows 11 and i'm using the latest version of Python and FiftyOne.

I try with another type of service like angular app for example, that use localhost and another port, and there wasn't problems.

Comment: Is port 5151 possibly being used by something else? If so, can FiftyOne (whatever that is) be configured to use custom ports?

Comment: I can specify what port can be used in python function to launch FiftyOne app, so i think yes. And no, the port is not being used

Comment: What is your Python version? Are you aware that FiftyOne is only supported on versions 3.7 -> 3.10 ? Have you contacted FiftyOne support? This doesn't sound like a Python issue *per se*

Answer (score 1):

You may be trying to launch the FiftyOne App in script? If so, [session.wait(-1)](https://docs.voxel51.com/faq/index.html#why-isn-t-the-app-opening-not-connected-to-a-session) should be used. Also note that on Windows, a [main](https://docs.voxel51.com/faq/index.html#why-can-t-i-open-the-app-from-a-script-on-windows) guard should also be used.

Comment: Yes, i solved the problem with this. Thank you